# What is the fastest way to set multiple PostgreSQL session variables at once?

Tags: postgresql

Let's say we have two session variables, as shown below:

```
SET my.role = 'public_user'; SET my.ip_address = '127.0.0.1';
```

If that line of SQL is executed in one statement, is that the fastest way of setting multiple session variables at once?

Answer (score 0):

Batching them reduces the round-trips and should save a few milliseconds. Not all client libraries allow multiple statements; make sure yours is actually sending all of them.